# Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVelocityTemplateRenderers is Missing in Sitecore 10.3

Tags: sxa

I am upgrading Sitecore from 9.1 to 10.3 and noticed the class `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Pipelines.GetVelocityTemplateRenderers` is no more present in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions`. Tried to find it in other dlls too but seems its totally removed.

We have written some custom code like https://michaellwest.blogspot.com/2017/04/custom-rendering-variant-token-tool-for-sxa.html

Any idea how to fix above class?

Answer (score 1):

NVelocity​ has been removed ([here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/93/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2093%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes#/Deprecated)). With the latest introduction of Scriban in `SXA 9.3.0` and more importantly the removal of NVelocity you will find that all of your NVelocity templates no longer work. Depending on what those NVelocity templates previously did, it should be possible to handle the majority of the logic within the [Sitecore SXA Scriban extensions](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/scriban-templates.html) or methods available directly in [Scriban](https://github.com/scriban/scriban).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  In future we are planning to move to XM cloud and I think I read somewhere that in XM cloud Scriban template is not supported. Any opinion/suggestion on this?

Comment: XMCloud is headless only. That a whole different thingy...